# How to increase team rating in Fifa 15 Ipad game?

Tags: ios, fifa-15

I am playing Fifa 15 UT in my iPad.

> Recently a new tournament started Team of the year and conditions to
>   be satisfied to play that particular tournament is Team Ration 82-99

at present my `Team rating` is `80` I tried hard to increase my team rating by buying players with good rating but still I cannot get required rating so please help me in suggesting tips to increase team rating.

Comment: Make sure your sub bench have players over or on par with 82 too. Then your team ration should be 82. Having players that are 85-87 will also help if you have any players that are 80